# Checkout File and AutoMerge Always Gives a Generic Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm using TFS 2010. Every single time I try and do a "Checkout File And AutoMerge", I get the following generic error message:

> Error
>
> The following exception was encountered.  NAMEOFFILE cannot be merged.
>   Please retry with another resolution option.

This doesn't tell me anything about why or how to resolve it. This is very frustrating because I cannot automerge anything and TFS doesn't give me a manual merge option either. Never thought I'd miss SVN so much. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Do you not see this file in the conflicts list?  Can you not then Merge in Merge Tool?

Comment: The only two options I have are "Checkout File and AutoMerge" or "Overwrite Local File or Folder". 

And even if I did have Manual Merge, I wouldn't expect AutoMerge to be unable to merge my very simple changes (like adding a blank line to a file).

Comment: What is the description of this conflict?  Is this a "writable file" conflict by chance?  How about a screenshot?